# An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator?

Tags: c#, linq

How can i increment the index value in linq statement.

```
  int headIndex = -1;
           // int itemIndex = -1;
            lst = (from xx in db.vwCustomizationHeaders
                   where xx.ProductID == pID
                   select new custHeader()
                   {
                       headIndex = headIndex++,// Guid.NewGuid(),
             }
```

Comment: Your query executes server-side.  Needless to say it's inconceivable that you could modify external variables.  You're going to have to execute the query first (`.ToArray()`, etc.) and then iterate over that to increment.  Furthermore, it's really poor practice to ever modify state in a `select` clause.

Comment: How should i modify not in select then..?

Comment: a `foreach` loop (over the result of `.ToArray`) would work just great.

Comment: Even if this were possible, which it is not, what on earth does `headIndex = headIndex++` mean? `headIndex++` already means "increment `headIndex`" so why would you then want an assignment to the thing you just incremented *from* the thing you just incremented?

Comment: They are two separate variable with same name, one is from object another is the local varible

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: Ah, I see, you are using an object initializer to assign to a field with a local of the same name.  **Please do not ever do this**. It makes the code extraordinarily hard to read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While you're *creating* this query in code:

```
from xx in db.vwCustomizationHeaders
where xx.ProductID == pID
select new custHeader()
{
    headIndex = headIndex++
}
```

It's actually *executed* at the database.  And the database can't modify values in your code.  So you can't increment that code-local value (`headIndex`) from the database.  (Additionally, as @Kirk Woll pointed out, it's very bad practice to modify values like that in a select.  A select should just fetch/build something, not alter state or produce side-effects.)

If all you're doing is updating that value, you don't need to use a select.  You can add the count of records to the value directly:

```
headIndex += db.vwCustomizationHeaders.Count(ch => ch.ProductID == pID);
```

The commented-out part suggests that you're also building a list of `vwCustomizationHeader`s though, something like this:

```
lst = (from xx in db.vwCustomizationHeaders
where xx.ProductID == pID
select new custHeader()
{
    SomeField = xx.SomeField,
    AnotherField = xx.SomeOtherField
    // etc.
});
```

From there you can use the `lst` object to modify your counter:

```
headIndex += lst.Count();
```

Comment: actually i need to attach a index so that i can iterate in anjualar.js at clietn side..

Comment: If i use Guid is that a god choice?

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: I wouldn't suggest a `Guid` unless there's a specific reason to use one.  If you just need to iterate, an integer will do the job just fine.  You can iterate over the values after you get them from the database, something like: `foreach (var item in lst) item.HeadIndex = headIndex++;`.  Naturally, your `select` would need to create a placeholder field: `select new custHeader() { HeadIndex = 0, SomeField = xx.SomeField, etc. }`